# How to run the same sequence on two different sequencers and having same values after randomization?

Tags: uvm

I want to run the same sequence on two different sequencers but the problem I am facing is randomisation is done after the sequence is started. So I am getting different sequence items. I want to have the same sequence items after the randomization. I am not getting what should I do?

Comment: Not sure the tools you're using, but like in https://verificationacademy.com/forums/ovm/how-manage-seed-randomization you should be able to set the seed of the random values, which allows to get the same random values twice (just reset to the seed before the 2nd sequence). Or you should be able to store the random numbers somewhere (before or during the first sequence), and call them from storage

Comment: how to have same sequence items after randomization?

Comment: How are you starting the sequences? Please provide some code so we can understand what you're doing. A [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be nice.